# Cool Diagrams - What software is being used here?

Tags: diagrams

I've seen some cool, nifty data diagrams done on some blogs/articles and have been wondering what software they were using to render these diagrams, e.g. MS Visio?  For example, what is used on this blog to create those colorful diagrams towards the middle of the article under "Definition Providers": http://www.thecodejunkie.com/2009/05/introduction-to-mef-programming-models.html?

I find these diagrams very appealing...

[EDIT - Addition]: I run across these diagrams all over the place, e.g. one of the bloggers I follow is Nikhil Kothari - http://www.nikhilk.net/Silverlight-Layout-Panels-1.aspx.

Comment: Instead of closing, move it to SuperUser, maybe.

Comment: I see the topic has been marked as closed, but as far as the diagrams I publish, I create them in powerpoint, and convert to png...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's from Office 2007, for sure. They can be created in Word, Excel and Powerpoint 2007.

Office has [a tutorial to create what they call a "SmartArt Graphic"](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint/HA012058671033.aspx)

[image: SmartArt Graphic creator]
<sub>(source: [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Microsoft-Office-Word-2007Images/Smartart_Graphic_Purposes___List_Show_Nonsequential_Information.PNG))</sub>

Here is a home made picture, from Word 2007 :)

[image: Home made picture]

Now with matching colors!

Comment: Looks like it... let me investigate further... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Those look pretty much like the diagrams you can generate with Word 2007 to me. Though it could have been some other software.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask one of the authors to be sure having the right answer...

Comment: I just left a comment on his blog entry... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna take a guess and say [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/omnigraffle/) for MacOS.

Comment: I don't think OmniGraffle has those shapes by default (in particular the shapes with thick arrows coming off of them). (It could be some special stencil set, though.)

Comment: Well I was wrong, big surprise :(